# C++ deleting from a vector of emails

Tags: c++, email, vector

I've emails loaded from a text file into a vector and I want to allow the user to enter an email of a sender and find that in the vector and delete that object,
but for some reason i'm getting an error.

here is the function

```
void deleteEmail(vector<Email> emailVector)
{
string junk;
getline(cin, junk);
cout << "Enter an email you want to delete" << endl;
string email_to_delete;
getline(cin, email_to_delete);
auto it = std::find(emailVector.begin(), emailVector.end(), email_to_delete);
if (it != emailVector.end())
    emailVector.erase(it);
for (Email e : emailVector)
    e.printEmail();
}
```

The error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2678   binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'Email' (or there is no acceptable conversion)   ProjectAlpha    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xutility 3258
```

Here are the datatypes in the Email class

```
class Email
{
private:
    string sender;
    string recipient;
    string time;
    string subject;
    string body;
    Attachment attachment;
```

Comment: The error message is fairly clear. There is no defined `operator==` that compares an `Email` with  a `std::string`. What exactly you don't understand?

Comment: How do you mean to search for the match?  `email_to_delete` is a string.

Comment: It makes sense now.. I dont know how to make the operator. I tried to delete by index but had difficulty as well.

Comment: why don't you use a set? it seems to be a better alternative than a vector. The operations that you are trying to do on a vector seems to be native to a set.

Comment: have to use a vector or a list

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass your `vector` by reference, not by value.  Otherwise, you are operating on a *copy* of the original vector, not the *original* vector.

As for your particular error, you can't use `std::find()` to find a `std::string` in a vector of `Email` objects, as your `Email` class does not have an `operator==` that accepts a `std::string` as input.  You can use `std::find_if()` with a predicate instead, eg:

```
void deleteEmail(vector<Email> &emailVector)
{
    cout << "Enter the sender email address you want to delete:" << endl;
    string email_to_delete;
    getline(cin, email_to_delete);
    auto it = std::find_if(emailVector.begin(), emailVector.end(),
        [](const Email &email) {
            // Email::sender is private, so you need
            // to provide public access to it...
            return (email.getSender() == email_to_delete);
        }
    );
    if (it != emailVector.end())
        emailVector.erase(it);
    for (Email &e : emailVector)
        e.printEmail();
}
```

If you want to remove *all* emails from the same `sender`, you can use `std::remove_if()` instead, eg:

```
void deleteAllEmail(vector<Email> &emailVector)
{
    cout << "Enter the sender email address you want to delete:" << endl;
    string email_to_delete;
    getline(cin, email_to_delete);
    auto it = std::remove_if(emailVector.begin(), emailVector.end(),
        [](const Email &email) {
            // Email::sender is private, so you need
            // to provide public access to it...
            return (email.getSender() == email_to_delete);
        }
    );
    emailVector.erase(it, emailVector.end());
    for (Email &e : emailVector)
        e.printEmail();
}
```